# How to install tomcat 8 in ubuntu 14.04 along with setting the path

Tags: networking

I tried to install tomcat 7 earlier, but while i was executing my application, the the java file could not run. Because the path was not set.

So please tell me How to install tomcat 8 in Ubuntu 14.04 along with setting the path.

Comment: How did you install tomcat 7 before and how did you execute applications on it?

Answer (score 0):

The latest Tomcat version for 14.04 is version 7. You can install the package via

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat7
```

Open the URL http://localhost:8080 in your browser and you will see the welcome page

[image]

That's all.

---

For version 8 you need Ubuntu 15.04 (or the end of life version 14.10).

Comment: Is your problem solved?